# how to express delta function in Fortran

Tags: fortran

In Fortran, to do the Monte Carlo integration, I want to times an extra factor which contains a Dirac Delta function like delta(1-x), how do I express delta function in Fortran? Is there anything like log(x)? or do I have to define a function? how?

Comment: There is no intrinsic function for that, so you have to implement something directly. There are so very many ways to implement this function, so what particular requirements do you have and what is currently troubling you?

Comment: I need to times a simple delta function into the integrand, so I think maybe need first to define the delta function, then the problem becomes how to define a delta function, finally as a factor times the delta function into the integrand.

Comment: A delta function is not really a function. Not even in math, so it cannot be a function in Fortran or any other language. It is a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) a and distributions are entities that act on test functions through integration (the Lebesgue integral is useful to know for the theory).

Comment: That said, you can normally integrate a function times the delta distribution very simply. The indefinite integral of *delta(a-x) * f(x)* is just *f(a)*. That is something you do on paper or in an algebra system when preparing you equations, you do not code this operation in Fortran. Therefore, I suggest to ask on https://math.stackexchange.com how you can simplify your integral. Some programs like Mathematica or Maple should also be able to do that.

Comment: You can mathematically construct the Dirac delta as a limit of certain sequences of functions. Such functions *can* be programmed in Fortran as functions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Representations_of_the_delta_function  But I would think twice whether this is really what you need.

Comment: As VladimirF says, you can't usefully implement a Dirac delta directly. Can you give us a [mre] of your Monte Carlo algorithm without a delta function? That way we can show you how to modify it to add in the delta.

Comment: Can you provide just a bit more detail on what you are trying to do (with some code maybe) in order to understand how you are trying to use the δ(x) function.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
program test_dirac
        use iso_fortran_env
        implicit none

        integer :: i
        real(real64) :: x

        do i=-10,10
           x = real(i,real64)
           print *, 'x=',x,' dirac=',dirac(x)
        end do

        contains


        elemental real(real64) function dirac(x)
            real(real64), intent(in) :: x
            real(real64) :: absx
            absx = abs(x)
            dirac = merge(1.0_real64/absx,0.0_real64,absx<epsilon(x))
        end function dirac

end program test_dirac
```

On gfortran-10, it returns:

```
 x=  -10.000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=  -9.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=  -8.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=  -7.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=  -6.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=  -5.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=  -4.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=  -3.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=  -2.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=  -1.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=   0.0000000000000000       dirac=                  Infinity
 x=   1.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=   2.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=   3.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=   4.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=   5.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=   6.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=   7.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=   8.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=   9.0000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
 x=   10.000000000000000       dirac=   0.0000000000000000
```

Comment: For the infinit value you are probably better using the facilities from the standard intrinsic module `ieee_arithmetic`

Comment: This will absolutely not work "to do the Monte Carlo integration"

Comment: Yeah comments have already pointed that out, my example tries to address the question “how to express delta function in Fortran” directly